# How to accept all data from connection in socketserver python?

Tags: python, tcp, recv, socketserver

How to receive all data from a connection in `socketserver` so that it the connection does not hang on the client side

```
class ConnectionHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = b''
        while 1:
            tmp =  self.request.recv(1024)
            if not tmp:
                break
            data += tmp 
        print (data.decode())
```

on the client side I am using

```
    char text[] = "Hello world\n";
    SSL_write(ssl, text, sizeof(text));

    char tmp[20];
    int received = SSL_read (ssl, tmp, 20);
    printf("Server replied: [%s]\n", tmp);
```

but this causes the connection not to close and the client hangs, I am sure this is the case since replacing the while loop with `self.request.recv(1024)` receives the client message and outputs it but what if i don't know the message size of the client

Answer (score 0):

Using `self.request.recv()` without an actual value on how many bytes to read seems to obtain the whole buffer from the client